# How to apply Dijkstra algorithm to find the optimal time for visiting shopping centres

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I tried this [Synchronous Shopping](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/synchronous-shopping/problem) problem on HackerRank and I had no clue how to approach it. So I looked at the editorial, and I am confused. Maybe I misunderstood how Dijkstra's single source shortest path algorithm works.

This is taken from the [editorial](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/synchronous-shopping/editorial):

He says

> The shortest distance to the state `D(V, B)` denotes the minimum time required
>   to visit shopping center `V` with fish from the mask `B` bought.

and then he describes two possible ways we might move from one state to another, and after that he says

> When all the minimal times are calculated....

I assume he means, we should have considered all possible ways to obtain fish, after we reach node **N**. All 2^k ways. Like, we consider

1) we only have the first fish when we reach node N

2) we only have the second fish...

3) we only have the first fish and the second fish..

etc..

but if we run Dijkstra, it will calculate the shortest path from node 1 to node N, but we have to travel a specific path to get from node 1 to node N. And we will only get the fish available along those nodes. How do we calculate all other states? (reaching node N with different sets of fish)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to help you, as I recently did the exercise. I will try to build the solution or the main idea piece by piece.

Summary of the problem: There're two cats, they start at the shopping 1 and goes until N. At each shopping they buy a set of fishes and they can only stop at N if both cats have bought all fishes. Both cats can go different paths and revisit shopping mall.

The objective of the problem is finding the minimum time of buying all fishes, which is the maximum time between the two cats reach N and the two together bought all fishes available.

Now, let's try to build the solution up: Imagine that you have no fishes and you only want to know the shortest time that a cat would take to go from shopping 1 to N. Dijkstra can solve this problem, right? It would calculate all the shortest time from the source (shop 1) to all other nodes.

Next step is adding the fishes: Now, assume that we have only one cat and we have to buy fishes at each stop. Try to imagine the following: Instead of each vertex of your graph being just the shopping mall is the shopping and a combination of the fishes that the cat bought so far, storing information.

This means that a shopping can be added more than once to the priority queue, which does not happen in the "normal" Dijkstra algorithm. This allows you to calculate the shortest time from the source and all possible combinations to reach that shopping with fishes bought. Unfortunately, this increases the number of vertices to O(N*2^(k-1)). Make sure you store the shortest time for all vertices, we will use this in the next step.

Another essential trick is keeping the fishes in a bitset instead of a list or vector as buying fishes is an OR operation. Most bitwise operations used are constant O(1).

The last step is adding the second cat:If you calculate the Dijkstra as mentioned below, you will get all the shortest time, for all vertices, which are states for all shopping and fishes bought. We are interested only in the cases where we are at the shop N and the combination of fishes bought by the cat 1 and 2 are equal to all fishes bought.

What has been taken into account is that if one cat arrives at N, it has to wait the other to arrive, meaning that no matter what were the fishes that one cat bought, if the other arrive if the rest, that's fine.

Technically, you will process all the possible scenarios available for the shopping N and if the combination of fishes of the cat 1 and 2 are equal to all fishes bought, you get the shortest time (the minimum among all possibilities).
This is unfortunately a exhaustive approach but passes fine. This is the two for stacked after the Dijkstra processing.